# CREATE VIEW AS SELECT FROM with check if table exists

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to check, when creating a view, that the table I am selecting from actually exists? To prevent **Invalid object name 'MyItems'** or **Incorrect syntax near keyword VIEW**.

```
-- ok this is super simplistic
-- but it is enough to illustrate the point
CREATE VIEW vw_MyView
AS
SELECT DISTINCT Id, Name, COUNT(CategoryId) OVER (PARTITION BY Id) AS Total
FROM MyItems
GO
```

I have a bunch of these views that get created as part of the batch script. In this example, if `MyItems` doesn't exist the execution breaks the entire batch script.

So, I thought I would just add a bunch of checks in front of every `CREATE VIEW` statement to make sure the table(s) actually exist.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[MyItems]') AND type IN (N'U'))
    -- CREATE VIEW <snip></snip>
GO
```

But as it turns out the `CREATE VIEW` statement must be the first statement in a query batch.

Back my question, is there some kind of workaround for catching when CREATE VIEW fails to complete because it is reading from none existent table?

I am using MS SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative using dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @sqlcmd NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @sqlcmd = 
'CREATE VIEW vw_MyView
 AS
 SELECT DISTINCT Id, Name, COUNT(CategoryId) OVER (PARTITION BY Id) AS Total
 FROM MyItems
 GO';

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[MyItems]') AND type IN (N'U'))
  BEGIN
    EXEC sp_executesql @sqlcmd
  END

ELSE
  BEGIN 
    PRINT 'Table doesnt exist'
  END
```

Answer (score 0):

This code May helps you,Try once

```
IF EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MyItems'
            AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
        )
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
            WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'vw_MyView'
                AND TABLE_TYPE = 'VIEW'
            )
    BEGIN
        CREATE VIEW vw_MyView
        AS
        SELECT DISTINCT Id
            ,NAME
            ,COUNT(CategoryId) OVER (PARTITION BY Id) AS Total
        FROM MyItems 
    END 
END
```

Comment: I already tried a few similar approaches and got CREATE VIEW statement must be the first statement in a query batch. This leads me to believe you cannot wrap CREATE VIEW in any other statement.